# Javascript validation alert is firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a scenario where I want to check some `regex` and fire the `alert` message if regex fails.

SO what happens is, when the alert is fired after clicking OK it fires the same alert again.

Below is the code:-

```
function validateSAPID() {
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/m;
        var strSAP = document.getElementById('txtSearchSAP').value;
        if (strSAP.match(regex)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("Please enter proper SAP ID");
            $('#txtSearchSAP').focus();
            $('#txtSearchSAP').val('');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and `textbox` HTML is below:-

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearchSAP" onkeyup='FilterGrid(this);' onblur="validateSAPID();" class="field-style field-full align-none" maxlength="18" />
```

Comment: wrap the .focus/.val lines in a setTimeout - by the way, firefox and chrome do NOT produce the behaviour you claim - what browser are you using and can you create a minimal *working* example where this occurs

Comment: @JaromandaX: I am checking that in CHROME

Comment: I've seen that pattern of code behave like that in Chrome, oddly, a simple test I wrote did not

Answer (score 0):

try to call validateSAPID(); inside FilterGrid(this); onkeyup event

Answer (score 0):

(I know my grammar is bad, so fell free to edit )

I have made some test and seems that `$("#txtSearchSAP").focus();` happens first and then is triggered `alert("Please enter proper SAP ID");` that cause to loose the focus and run again the function.

Im not sure if is the most efficient way to do it but this is the solution that I get:

```
   <body >
      <input type="text" id="txtSearchSAP"    class="field-style field-full align-none" maxlength="18" />
   </body>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#txtSearchSAP").focusout(function(){
                 var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/m;
                 var strSAP = $("#txtSearchSAP").val();
                 if (strSAP.match(regex) == null) {
                    alert("Please enter proper SAP ID");
                  }
                  setTimeout(function(){
                     $("#txtSearchSAP").val("");
                     $("#txtSearchSAP").focus();
                  }, 1);
            });
      });
   </script>
```